# Where are temporary files when pandas' to_csv() is still working?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am processing a big file whose pickle size is 44.5 GB. I have tried to store it with a csv format, using pandas' library and its `to_csv()`  function, as follows:

```
data.to_csv("data.csv")
```

In the destination folder, the size of the so-called `"data.csv"` file is 0 kB, but it is using Disk. Meanwhile I need to stop the process, but I am afraid if I can't find the temporary data (which is of course quite big).
Any help on where the temporary file is stored, during executing this function?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I'm anxious about whether I will not be ever able to find it. Then I'll have to clean-reinstall the Windows OS? :(

Comment: There is no temporary file, the data is being prepared to write to disk from RAM. Once the preparation is done and the file is being written to disk, you would see the file size increasing gradually. If you stop in the middle of the process, the file is broken.

Comment: Look, RAM usage increased instantly, and then it came back within 2 minutes to where it was. Then only disk and CPU have been working for more than 20 minutes now. @QuangHoang

Comment: This might not be the correct approach, as the file size is too large. I would suggest you to get the first million rows (or so) from the pickle file and convert them to a csv file, then the next million rows and so on. Finally you could try to combine the resultant csv files together.

Comment: I think this is due to Windows behavior (you are using Windows, right?). If you run the same code in Ubuntu, you will see the file size increase while writing. This difference can be seen generally when writing files and is not a pandas-specific problem.